# startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler only returns friends who use the app

Tags: ios, facebook

Before I upgraded to the latest Facebook SDK, I was able to call "startForMyFriendsWithCompletionHandler" and get a complete list of my Facebook friends back.

Now, I only get a list of friends who have installed my app.

How do I get the entire list like I used to?

Comment: You can't get all friends. It is by design that you only get friends that installed the app

Comment: The whole point of my app integrating with Facebook is so you could share data with your Facebook friends. A lot of apps do this.

Comment: Share how? What would you do if you got all friends?

Comment: Allow my user to pick friends with which to share the content that he creates in my app, and send those friends a notification to get the app. This was all working before I upgrade the SDK.

Comment: Use the send or share dialog

Comment: As of April 2015, Facebook will no longer return all friends, only friends with the app.  Old apps still do it, but will have to update soon.